# Corona SDK Google Play license check

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I have made a payed app for Android with Corona SDK, and I was wondering if there is anyway to  check if the person actually bought the app instead of pirating it. I know this is possible to do in other SDKs

If it is possible, could anyone tell me how to set it up?

Any replies are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No longer required :D

All the information is here: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/licensing/index.html